# TypeError: existExecution.addGroup is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

I am integrating ORM with sequelize to the express project. The database is MySQL DB. 
I have some problems in integrating many to many relationships. 
Here are two models that I am going to integrate many to many relationships.

```
export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Execution = sequelize.define('execution', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    group_by: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    group_order: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    sort_by: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    sort_order: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  })

  return Execution
}
```

```
export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const ExecutionGroup = sequelize.define('Group', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    order: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'execution_group'
  })

  return ExecutionGroup
}
```

And this is the relationship model.

```
export default (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const ExecutionGroupRelation = sequelize.define('execution_group_relation', {}, {
    timestamps: false
  })

  return ExecutionGroupRelation
}
```

Here is my code for integrating many to many relationships.

```
Group.belongsToMany(Execution, {
    through: ExecutionGroupRelation,
  })
```

I am trying to call addGroup function, but it says it isn't declared.
Now, how can I add groups to the execution?
I can share more detail about what you want.

Let me share the reference document I followed.
https://www.bezkoder.com/sequelize-associate-many-to-many/#Sequelize_Many-to-Many_example_Overview

From this document, I can't find out the `TagController.addTutorial` function's code.

```
TagController.addTutorial(tag1.id, tut1.id);
```

This code showing addTutorial is not defined error.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you check if `Execution` have the non-empty `associations` prop? If so you can further check what methods `Execution` has at runtime

Comment: Hi @Anatoly! Thank you for your kind reply. How can I check if `Execution` has the non-empty `associations` prop?

Comment: Just set a breakpoint on the line right before the line that causes the error and look at `Execution` or try to output it to console

Comment: Hi @Anatoly! I followed this tutorial: (https://www.bezkoder.com/sequelize-associate-many-to-many/#Sequelize_Many-to-Many_example_Overview). The thing what I can't understand is this code: ( `TagController.addTutorial(tag1.id, tut1.id);` ). I can't findout TagController/addTutorial function code. addTutorial is not defined. Could you tell me how can I solve this problem, please?
Thank you.

Comment: I see `addTutorial` in this guide. Maybe you placed it in the incorrect controller?

Comment: I didn't define `addTutorial` function in any controller. And I can't find `addTutorial` function code from the reference documentation.

Comment: But this guide contains the whole working example including controllers, models and so on. Then look at the definition of `addTutorial` in the guide to find out what it does

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It works. Thank you.
 Could you add your answer to my question, please? So I can approve your answer.

Comment: Hi @Anatoly! Did you have a chance to check my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out how to fix `addGroup` issue and find the definition of `addTutorial` just following the tuturial and use the whole code from there and look at `addTutorial` function definition in `TagController`

Comment: Could you tell me what happened if I didn't declare the addTutorial function on the controller?

Comment: It's just a wrapper function to check if a tutorial record exists and if not then add it to an indicated tag

Comment: Ok, thank you. :+1

Comment: Could you upvote my question, kindly?

Comment: I have a feeling that you confused a generated method in a model instance by Sequelize and the ones in the tutorial that just written manually

Comment: I can see, I can use the `addTutorial` function without a definition of that function. The important thing is the model name should be `tutorial`. Am I right? I can use the `addTutorial` function without definition and it works well.

Comment: yes, if a child model named `tutorial` then a parent model should have methods like `addTutorial`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your kind reply. Could you upvote this question, if you think this question is useful for the others like me? Thank you.